# React: updating parent state from nested children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm working in a form with React. My idea is to create a reusable Form component that gets the state from a Page component as props, and will hold the logic for updating its own state with children data, send it to parent Page component.

The Page component is this:

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        text1: "Initial text1",
        text2: "Initial text2"
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Page">
        <div className="DataPreview">
          Data preview in Page component
          <div>{this.state.data.text1}</div>
          <div>{this.state.data.text2}</div>
        </div>
        <Form data={this.state.data}>
          <Input id="text1" data={this.state.data.text1} />
          <Input id="text2" data={this.state.data.text2} />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the Form component:

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.props.data;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Parent">
        <div>Form component</div>
        <div className="DataPreview">
          Data preview in Form component
          <div>{this.state.text1}</div>
          <div>{this.state.text2}</div>
        </div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this the Input component:

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Child" id={this.props.id}>
        <div>Input component</div>
        <input id={this.props.id} type="text" value={this.props.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So Input should update Form state, and Form should update Page state. I know how to do it passing a callback when the Input is written Inside Form component, but I cant figure out how to do it when it is written inside Page component, like in this case.

I have a Sandbox for those interested: https://codesandbox.io/s/qx6kqypo09

Comment: Try to use Redux or Flux. That would be better.

Comment: What I didn't said is that my Page component gets data from Redux via Connector component. But, how would you take advantage of Redux in this case?

Comment: Don't follow this logic. This is not how React works. You can't see many applications like that. If you need to update the parent's state, just do it with a handler function like you thought. Also, why do you have your `Input` component as a child? You can directly use it in the `Form` component.

Comment: You can use react 'context'

Comment: @devserkan The idea is that Form only takes care of updating the data of the Inputs. I want it to be reusable, so I can't write the inputs inside Form component. Otherwise I would end up with one Form component for each specific form in my project, which is not DRY. How can I add a handler function to a child component in my case?

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani how would you use context in this case?

Comment: I understand the DRY part but with this logic, you are repeating and copying the state (data) in many places. For example, you are passing a separate piece of data to your every Form children. How practical is this?

Comment: After reading all the comments and solutions, I understand that the state should be managed by the form, and all the components should be written inside it to get the correct `this` —Form component—. I will update the question as soon as possible to check the proper way to handle a form.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Input extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let data = this.props.this.state.data;
    data.text1 = e.target.value;
    this.props.this.setState({ data: data });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Child" id={this.props.id}>
        <div>Input component {this.props.id}</div>
        <input
          id={this.props.id}
          type="text"
          value={this.props.data}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

use your input component as specified and your page component as mentioned below-

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {
        text1: "Initial text1",
        text2: "Initial text2"
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Page">
        <div className="DataPreview">
          Data preview in Page component
          <div>{this.state.data.text1}</div>
          <div>{this.state.data.text2}</div>
        </div>
        <Form data={this.state.data}>
          <Input id="text1" this={this} data={this.state.data.text1} />
          <Input id="text2" data={this.state.data.text2} />
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think this will help you 
Thanks

Comment: Passing `this` as a prop and handling the state like that? I've never seen any use like that. Never in good tutorials, even in regular ones.

Comment: I'm not talking about if it works or not. Nevermind, everyone has her/his own ways.

Answer (score 1):

As @dashton said, I am holding the same state in different components, and that's not correct. I will look for a different approach instead using only `Form` component state, and sharing logic via composition. I will open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

without using some kind of state management, you would need to create a method that handles the state change in the parent component that you would then pass down to your child component a a prop.

Once you call that method in the child component it will update the state of the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing what you want to achieve: passing a callback handler for `onChange`. But, when your app starts to get bigger things can be ugly :) If you are thinking about creating a complex reusable `Form` component maybe you can examine the present node packages.

An alternative to this method, if you need a simple one, you can study React Context a little bit. It can help you maybe. Other than that Redux or other global state management libraries can do this also.

```js
class Page extends React.Component {
state = {
  data: {
    text1: "Initial text1",
    text2: "Initial text2",
  },
};

handleChange = ( e ) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState( prevState => ( {
    data: { ...prevState.data, [ name ]: value },
  } ) );
}


render() {
  return (
    <div className="Page">
      <div className="DataPreview">
          Data preview in Page component
        <div>{this.state.data.text1}</div>
        <div>{this.state.data.text2}</div>
      </div>
      <Form data={this.state.data}>
        <Input name="text1" data={this.state.data.text1} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <Input name="text2" data={this.state.data.text2} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
}

const Form = props => (
  <div className="Parent">
    <div>Form component</div>
    <div className="DataPreview">
      Data preview in Form component
      <div>{props.data.text1}</div>
      <div>{props.data.text2}</div>
    </div>
    {props.children}
  </div>
);

const Input = props => (
  <div className="Child" id={props.id}>
    <div>Input component {props.id}</div>
    <input name={props.name} type="text" value={props.data} onChange={props.onChange} />
  </div>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, rootElement);
```

```css
.Page {
  border: 10px solid blue;
}
.Parent {
  border: 10px solid turquoise;
}
.Child {
  border: 3px solid tomato;
}
.DataPreview {
  border: 3px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the idea is to set this logic inside Form…

Comment: If so, what happens when your state changes in the `Page` component at the same time in the `Form` component? Which state will be the correct one? If I understood you wrong if you don't keep a state in the `Form` why are you assigning a state to its prop there? Why don't you use the props directly?

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, you are holding the same state in different components, which obviously isn't correct.

However, to answer your requirement regarding decoupling child components from the form, you could make your form handle state changes from the inputs by using a [render](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) prop which would pass a callback to the inputs, see code and link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/4zyvjm0q64

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Input extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleChange(id, value) {
        this.props.onChange(id, value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Child" id={this.props.id}>
                <div>Input component {this.props.id}</div>
                <input
                    id={this.props.id}
                    type="text"
                    value={this.props.data}
                    onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.data;
    }

    handleChange = (id, value) => {
        this.setState({ [id]: value });
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Parent">
                <div>Form component</div>
                <div className="DataPreview">
                    Data preview in Form component
                    <div>{this.state.text1}</div>
                    <div>{this.state.text2}</div>
                </div>
                {this.props.render(this.handleChange)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Page extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {
                text1: "Initial text1",
                text2: "Initial text2"
            }
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Page">
                <div className="DataPreview">
                    Data preview in Page component
                    <div>{this.state.data.text1}</div>
                    <div>{this.state.data.text2}</div>
                </div>
                <Form
                    data={this.state.data}
                    render={(handler) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                <Input id="text1" onChange={e => handler("text1", e.target.value)} />
                                <Input id="text2" onChange={e => handler("text2", e.target.value)} />
                            </div>
                        );
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, rootElement);
```